# Cloudera installation failed to detect root privileges on CentOS

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I tried to adding new host into the cluster o CentOS. It fails on install & gives "Installation failed. Failed to detect root privileges" in status.
I know that Cloudera needs user to have passwordless privileges ("Root access to your hosts is required to install the Cloudera packages. This installer will connect to your hosts via SSH and log in either directly as root or as another user with password-less sudo/pbrun privileges to become root."). How can I achieve that? I tried to edit the /etc/sudoers file.
EDIT: in sudoers file, I added the line:

> cdh  ALL=(ALL): ALL #cdh is my username

just under where permissions for 'root' is defined.

but with no more success at the install. In the Details window, it says:

```
Detecting root privileges...
effective UID is 502
BEGIN which pbrun 
END (1) 
BEGIN sudo -S id 
[sudo] password for cdh: 
Sorry, try again. 
[sudo] password for cdh: 
Sorry, try again. 
[sudo] password for cdh: 
Sorry, try again. 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts 
END (1) 
need root privileges but sudo requires password, exiting 
closing logging file descriptor.
```

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need root privileges without password , so your /etc/sudoers line will look something like this,

```
cloudera ALL =(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on Ubuntu:

Edit `/etc/sudoers`

Add  line:

```
 userid ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Instead of **userid** put your username with sudo privileges which you used to install Cloudera.

In installation step before, where you add host, make sure than that your have entered that username and password.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/sudoers` uncomment this line

```
## Same thing without a password
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```